# Import a Specific Table from an Existing Excel Workbook to Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to import a table from an existing Excel Workbook to Access. I have no problem when I try to import specific Cells, but there is an error when I try to import a named table.

The table I want to import is called `Projectlist_1` and this is the code I wrote:

```
Sub Import_Projectlist()
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim WB As String

    FilePath = "C:\Users\Projects\Tool\"
    WB = Dir(FilePath)

    Do While WB <> “”
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Project List", FilePath & WB, True, "Projectlist_1!"
        WB = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

If I change the code reference to the cells the table is at, it works correctly, but I need to take the whole table because it changes while I add or delete projects.

Example:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Projektliste", FilePath & WB, True, "Sheet1!B2:J75"
```

I'll be really grateful for the help because I've been struggling with this code for a while.

Comment: Why not import the whole sheet without specifying cells: `"Sheet1!"`? Per [TransferSpreadsheet docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferspreadsheet), *range* argument only takes valid range of cells not any other named object.

Comment: Range argument can specify a range by cell references or range name, but not a table name.

Comment: Note that the double-quotes used in the test expression for your `Do While` statement are not ASCII 34 quotes, but are ASCII 147 & 148 - this will cause problems.

Comment: Does the table start at a specific range with a fixed number of columns? In other word, is the number of rows the only variable in your import?

Answer (score 0):

Use the *name of the worksheet*. If a table is present on the worksheet, that will be imported, not the full worksheet:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12XML, "Projektliste", FilePath & WB, True, "Sheet1$"
```

Comment: I tested this and the full worksheet is pulled, not just the table area.

Comment: It works if the worksheet only contains the table (placed anywhere). So try moving/copying the table to an empty worksheet.

Comment: Then it's just importing all the data found on that sheet. Kinda defeats the purpose of defining a table if you have to copy its data somewhere to restrict the import. As far as I can tell, a table is just display formatting. It turns on the header filter and colors cells. Rows/columns added within its boundaries will adopt format. Once a table name is defined, have to convert to Range to get rid of.